# asp.net can't press "back" button because of field validator

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some textboxes in my asp.net site and also some field validators for that textboxes.
Now I've added a "back" button to go back to another page, but I can't press the button when not every field is filled.
Do you have any sugestions how to solve this problem?

aspx:

```html
<asp:TextBox ID="tbInformation" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Height="130px" Width="550px" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ID="rfvInformation" ControlToValidate="tbInformation" ErrorMessage="*Required*" />
```

Comment: Add `CausesValidation=false` to the back button.

Comment: ok wow, that was pretty simple

thank you very much :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.